# About embeddings of real grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals, grassmannian, real-algebraic-geometry

I am dealing with the embedding of real grassmannians $G(n,k)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ via the map associating to each vector space the projection matrix on it in the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^n$. More explicitely this map is defined identifying:
\begin{equation}
G(n,k)=\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\,|\,A^2=A,\,A^{T}=A,\, trace(A)=k\}.
\end{equation}
In ''Real Algebraic Geometry'' by Bochnak, Coste, Roy they prove that the map defined as before is a birational isomorphism between the grassmannian, as an abstract variety, and the algebraic set defined above. Is it also true that, as for the Plucker embedding, the equations defining this algebraic set are also generators for the vanishing ideal of polynomials? Is there a reference where to find something about it? Are there other ways to embed grassmannians getting that the equations defining the affine algebraic set are also generators of the vanishing ideal of polynomials?

Comment: In don't understand: the Grassmannians are projective variety, how can one embed them in an affine space?

Comment: This is a particular property of real grassmannians, for instance you can use the embedding a was talking about and all details can be found in "Real Algebraic Geometey" in chapter 3. Otherwise, you can embed the grassmannians in a protective space by the Plucker embedding and then embed the protective space in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ by \begin{equation} f(x_0:\dots:x_n)=\left(\frac{x_ix_{j}}{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}\right)_{i,j=1,\dots n}\end{equation} As you can see in this second embedding one uses the sum of squares, thus this construction is completely real and not complex.